# How to debug a 32bit executable in a 64bit system with kdbg?

Tags: kdbg

I have tried- `kdbg nameoftheexecutable` though kdbg start but its total empty. And no output either.

Just for additional informatin with `./nameoftheexecutable` i can get the expected output and cutter seems work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here on Linux, this works automatically, no special setup is required.

Did you compile with `-g`?

---

Just in case you really need to select a specific GDB for debugging, follow these steps:

- Run `kdbg nameoftheexecutable`.
- Select *Settings->Global Options*.
- Copy the GDB invocation listed in *How to invoke GDB*.
- Close the dialog.
- Select *Settings->This Program*.
- Paste the GDB invocation command into *How to invoke GDB*.
- Adjust the command to invoke the GDB version you need.